# How to run cypress test on arm-7 architecture

Tags: cypress

Is there a possibility to create a binary for running cypress tests on an arm 7 architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress is currently only built for [Windows, Linux, and macOS ia32 and x64](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Download-URLs).

You can open up a new issue to request builds for this architecture, to my knowledge you are the first person to request builds for ARM: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just opened an issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4478